# excluding a page from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

I have a swipe to do back script for my ios web app that I have running across every page but what I want to know how is to exclude from affecting the first page that shows up. The script is this

```
<script>
$(document).bind('swiperight', function () {
        history.back();
    });</script>
```

How would exclude a page that has a hypothetical id of "home"?

Comment: What do you mean by "a page that has a hypotherical id of "home""? Is that id part of the URL, specified on an element on the page, somewhere else?

Comment: How do you define the 'page' that is currently shown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using jQuery mobile (Apologies if you're not), you could use $.mobile.activePage to check if you're at home:

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/methods.html (At the bottom)

```
<script>
    $(document).bind('swiperight', function () {
        if ( $.mobile.activePage !== 'home' )
          history.back();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).bind('swiperight', function () {
    if (!$('body#home').length === 0) {
         history.back();
         // ... anything else
    }
});
```

You could also use: `if (!$('#page.home').length === 0)` if it's going to be a class on a containing element, `if ($('#page').hasClass('home'))` is a bit more of solid jQuery-y way of doing it too.

Comment: Elements can't have 2 IDs. -1

Comment: `$('#page').is('#home')` is *always* going to fail, because it can only be one or the other.

Comment: Calling the jQuery function *always* returns an object, which is considered truthy, so doing `!$('body#home')` won't ever be false, even if there's no `<body id="home">` element on the page - you need to use the length property to check if elements matched: `if($('body#home').length === 0)`

Comment: You're right again... I think my brain has died slightly today! Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

The general principle would be this:

```
<script>
var id = // get your hypothetical id from somewhere;
if(id !== "home") {
    $(document).bind('swiperight', function () {
        history.back();
    });
}
</script>
```

Without any more information on where the hypothetical id is coming from it's difficult to be more specific than that.

Comment: What I meant by hypothetical id is a place holder id so that I could reuse is and just replace "home" with what ever I needed. The basic purpose of excluded the first page shown is that so the user won't accidentally go back to another page.

Comment: @user2055617 Right, you have an id that is theoretically equal to the string `home`. In order to do what you want, you have to compare something against that string - where is that something coming from? Basically, where on your home page are you indicating that it **is** the home page - ideally you'd post something explicit, like some HTML or the page URL, to answer this.